# Why is useState hook changing another object without calling it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component that retrieves data when it first loads.

```
const [data, setDate] = useState(null);
const [originalData, setOriginalData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fn() {
      let res = await getObject();
      setData({...res});
      setOriginalData({...res});
    }

    fn();
}, [])
```

I call 2 different hooks to set the `data` and `originalData` states.

The purpose of this is so that I have an unchanged version of data that I can refer to for some of the logic in the component.

However when I make a change to the `data` state it seems to also be changing the `originalData` state as well without me calling anything.

```
const change() => {
    let updatedData = {...data};
    updatedData.someProperty = 'newValue';
    setData(updatedData);
}
```

I would have expected that data now contains the property `someProperty` with the value `newValue`, and that `originalData` will be unchanged from the initial load.

But when I compare them, `data` and `originalData` both now have `someProperty`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: add spread operator

Comment: First of all please put in the right code that is syntactically correct. Secondly, can you explain more about when your change function is getting called?

Comment: You need to create a deep copy of `res` to store in originalData.  Otherwise when you do `updatedData.foo.bar = 'new value';` you are updating the same foo as `originalData.foo`, because `{...data}` only makes a shallow copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem: Same Reference

The reason why changing `data` changes `originalData` is not because of React hooks, but because of the way objects behave in JavaScript. Though `data` and `originalData` are different, they are still referring to the same object (from `res`). *So any changes made to either one of these will be reflected on the other, since they have same reference.*

## Solution: Clone

For this reason you should **clone the data** instead of directly assigning them.

```js
// JSON 
const originalData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))

// Object.assign
const originalData = Object.assign({}, res)

// Or spread opr
const originalData = { ...res }

// Then set the state
setOriginalData(originalData);
```

ES6 methods like Object.assign and spread operator does a shallow copy. If you need a deep copy and if your data doesn't have Dates, functions, undefined, Infinity, RegExps, Maps, Sets, Blobs, FileLists, ImageDatas, sparse Arrays, Typed Arrays or other complex types within your object, go for JSON parse, stringify.

Check out this [question](/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) for more details about cloning in JavaScript

Comment: I was using the spread operator originally, but using a deep clone method seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.